# SQL Server 2016 Autocomplete Problems

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, autocomplete, intellisense

In my query editor window, when I write an `OVER()` clause and use `PARTITION BY`, for example, when I write `PARTITION` and hit `spacebar`, it autocompletes with `partition_fragment_id`.  I have to always hit `escape` before `spacebar`.

How can I turn this off without turning off all IntelliSense?

Comment: You can't if you stick with the native intellisense. It has been doing this for since 2008 when intellisense first hit the scene. It is frustrating to say the least. There are some great third party intellisense replacements out there. SQL Prompt from Redgate is one I really like.

Comment: It's just odd because I write PARTITION BY clauses all the time and this just started happening, but IntelliSense was enabled and working to autofill table names no problem before.